# Extreme query optimization with IN clause and subquery

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

My table has more than 15 millions of rows just now.
I need to run such query:

```
SELECT ch1.* FROM citizens_dynamic ch1
WHERE ch1.id IN (4369943, ..., 4383420, 4383700)
AND ch1.update_id_to = (
    SELECT MAX(ch2.update_id_to)
    FROM citizens_dynamic ch2
    WHERE ch1.id = ch2.id AND ch2.update_id_to < 812
)
```

Basically, for every citizen in `IN` clause it searches for a row with closest but lower than specified `update_id_to`.

There is PRIMARY key on 2 columns columns `update_id_to, id`.
At the moment, this query is executed in 0.9s (having 100 ids in `IN` clause).
It's still too slow, I would need to run my scripts for 3 days to complete.

Below you can see my `EXPLAIN` output.
[image: phpmyadmin explain output]

`id` index is just like PRIMARY key, but with reversed columns: `id, update_id_to`

Do you have any ideas how to make it even faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that MySQL tends to perform better with JOIN than correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT ch1.*
FROM citizens_dynamic AS ch1
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(update_id_to) AS update_id_to
      FROM citizens_dynamic
      WHERE id IN (4369943, ..., 4383420, 4383700)
      GROUP BY id) AS ch2
    ON ch1.id = ch2.id
WHERE ch1.id IN (4369943, ..., 4383420, 4383700)
```

Also, see the other methods in this question:

[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)